# SCNBillboardConstraint isn’t working. Node with constraint doesn’t change

Tags: ios, macos, camera, scenekit

Perhaps I am not setting up the camera properly… I’m starting with a scn file with a camera. In Xcode, rotating the free camera around, the geometries rotate as expected. However, at runtime, nothing happens.

It doesn’t seem to matter if I add the constraint in code or in the editor. The look at constraint works.

It also doesn’t seem to matter if I use the camera from the scn file or if I add a camera in code.

The sample code is

```
class Poster: SCNNode {
    let match:GKTurnBasedMatch

    init(match:GKTurnBasedMatch, width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat) {
        self.match = match

        super.init()

        // SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
        self.geometry = SCNBox(width: width, height: height, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0) 

        self.constraints = [SCNBillboardConstraint()]

        self.updatePosterImage()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your sample code?

Comment: Do you have any code controlling the camera's response to input?

Answer (score 2):

So… I gave up on the billboard constraint.

I’m using a SCNLookAtConstraint that looks at the camera node, with the gimbal lock enabled.

I was using a SCNPlane but it was doing weird stuff. So I went with a SCNBox for the geometry.

So, in the constructor:

```
self.geometry = SCNBox(width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0) 
let it = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: cameraNode)
it.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
self.constraints = [it]
```

It works.

Comment: I did that. But I’ll try it again :)

Comment: The billboard constraint is exactly what I was looking for. In one scene, it seems to work as expected. But in the scene that I need it, it is doing nothing. I don’t know why the scenes would be different :(

Comment: `SCNBillboardConstraint` still behaving badly in 2022. Had a similar problem to the one you had here. Eventually used the same strategy as this, minus the gimbal lock, and that (finally, after much anguish) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing ".init()" on the SCNBillboardConstraint(). This line alone did all the work for me:

```
node.constraints = [SCNBillboardConstraint.init()]
```

Comment: `init` is implied and can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

A constraint that orients `theNode` to always point toward the current camera.

```
   // Create the constraint
   SCNBillboardConstraint *aConstraint = [SCNBillboardConstraint billboardConstraint];

   theNode.constraints = @[aConstraint];
```

`theNode` is the node you want pointing to the camera.  This should work.

**Updated**

Ok, if you were to create a sample Project with the Game template.  And then make the following changes:

```
// create a clone of the ship, change position and rotation
SCNNode *ship2 = [ship clone];
ship2.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 4, 0);
ship2.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0, M_PI_2, 0);
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:ship2];

// Add the constraint to `ship`
SCNBillboardConstraint *aConstraint = [SCNBillboardConstraint billboardConstraint];
ship.constraints = @[aConstraint];
```

`ship` is constrained but `ship2` isn't.

If you were to add this:

```
       ship2.constraints = @[aConstraint];
```

Now, both will face the camera.  Isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: Oh, how I wished that worked. I’ve tried that in a number of ways. When the node is created, after the node gets added to its parents children, etc.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are you using the [`allowsCameraControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1523171-allowscameracontrol) property on `SCNView`?

If so, remember setting that will add a *new* camera to your scene (cloning an existing camera if one is present to match its settings), so if you create a constraint to your own camera, the constraint will *not*  be linked to the camera that’s actually being used.

Per Apple in their WWDC 2017 video, they say that property is really for debugging purposes, not for a real-world use.

Simply put, you have to ensure you are moving around your own camera, not relying on the auto-created one.